# Pushing GIT branch to heroku master

Tags: git, github, heroku

EDIT:

My branch name: heroku-deployment
My remote heroku: heroku-test

```
* e263761 (HEAD -> heroku-deployment, heroku-test/master) test
* 88b6e1a (origin/heroku-deployment) 'test'
* 3e828f7 test
* 90108ab (heroku-test/main) update application properties
* ec8378a application prop pointing to heroku cloud creds
* 2b288cd (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) first commit
```

I'm trying to push my code to heroku master from my git branch and but it's not happening and here is what I have used my commands

```
git push -f heroku local_branch_name:master
```

and also use this:

```
git push local_branch_name $(git branch --show-current):master
```

> error: unknown option `show-current):master'

Comment: The first option should work. What does "not happening" mean?

Comment: The second option makes me think you're on Windows, in which case you won't be able to use that syntax.

Comment: ah you are right I'm windows so make sense why this is not working the second option

Comment: Great, so let's focus on the first command. How is this failing to do what you want?

Comment: the first option when I ran it does not push the branch code rather it pushes the master branch force and even though I'm NOT on the master branch

Comment: It shouldn't. Are you sure your `local_branch_name` is different from your local `master`? Can you show your commit graph, either via screenshot or by copying the output of `git log --decorate --graph --all --oneline`?

Comment: And you're saying when you do `git push -f heroku-test heroku-deployment:master` commit `2b288cd` is being deployed to `heroku-test`? You see that commit ID in the logs? It looks like `heroku-test/master` is at the right place based on that commit graph: `e263761 (HEAD -> heroku-deployment, heroku-test/master) test`.

Comment: @Chris my end goal is the push my local_branch to heroku master

Comment: I don't see a literal `local_branch` in that commit graph, but that's what `git push heroku-test local_branch:master` does. The `-f` forces, which should only be done when you know for sure you want to overwrite what's already there. And the commit graph you shared shows that you have successfully pushed your local `heroku-deployment` branch to the `master` branch of your `heroku-test` remote.

Comment: when I say `local_branch` I meant `heroku-deployment` the log shows in the heroku my code is not from the `heroku-deployment` branch i don't see my latest changes

Comment: Please [edit] your question and expand upon "the log shows in the heroku my code is not from the `heroku-deployment` branch". I also see a `heroku-test/main` branch on commit `90108ab`, and [Heroku builds from both `main` and `master`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1829). Did you maybe push to that branch after pushing to `heroku-test/master`?

Comment: yes when I first push my code I did from `master` and then create a branch (`heroku-deployment`) from the `master` and I have been trying to push from branch `heroku-deployment`

Comment: Again, the commit graph you shared shows that your local `heroku-deployment` branch and the `heroku-test/master` branches are on the same commit: `e263761 (HEAD -> heroku-deployment, heroku-test/master) test`. Have you also deployed from another machine? Is this commit graph out of date? Try `git fetch heroku-test`. But also, again, please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by "the log shows in the heroku my code is not from the `heroku-deployment` branch". What you have shared so far suggests that you have already deployed the branch you want to deploy.